# RailsAdmin - preventing N+1 queries via includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Does anyone know of a way to configure that?  Or another DB query optimization technique?

I am using Rails 4.1.8 with RailsAdmin 0.6.8 and Mongoid 4.0.2

Comment: can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: Let's say I have customers and orders.  I want to view the order list but I want to display customer name next to each order.  RailsAdmin will query for each customer individually by customer_id (N+1 queries are slow).  If I were building this using regular controllers/views, I would simply put includes(:customers) in my orders index controller.  How do I do that in RailsAdmin?

Comment: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2427 Looks like this is an issue that hasn't been resolved yet.